# Ran :(){ :|: & };: on my android device!

Tags: 7.0-nougat, terminal

So I was seeing dangerous command  in linux and I found a command which seemed funny:

```
:(){ :|: & };:
```

So I ran it on my Samsung Galaxy A7 term non-rooted phone and guess what it hung immediately. So I tried powering off my phone by holding the power button. But it did not respond and the screen turned off after a minute then I tried clicking the home button and all the buttons to wake it up but no response finally it powered off and rebooted and now it works perfectly fine. Should I worry about heat damage or hardware damage. If so how can I confirm that I have a damaged hardware. Developer mode in on too!

PS. I have my phone powered off fro safety because I don't want it to catch fire. XD

Comment: There isn't really a "Developer mode" in Android. It just makes a new settings page appear. If you don't change any settings on that page, having the new page does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Modern Android Kernels are smart enough to shut down the entire system before any hardware damage occurs. Even when you're testing the limits of your CPU when overclocking, it will shut down as soon as incompatible frequency/voltage combination is set. So you're far from any real hardware damage cause by the infinite loop command.

Answer (score 0):

It's just called [fork bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb), a classic old technique to exhaust the resources of the computer, and render it unable to take care of other processes in the system by eating up (consuming) the memory.

Today's kernels are well-sophisticated and can even detect infinite recursive forks. To answer your question, no, it's not at all any harmful to your Android device (it just completely exhausts your RAM). All it takes is a reboot to fix it.